# Time Series Data and SAS

Tags: time-series, sas

I have a time series data set with 54 observations. I need to use the SAS software. I am aware that I can create a dataset in the SAS library and then open it. however i am not able to open the data and run my model. can anyone help me??

Comment: You can use proc import or import data from file->import data directly

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's SAS coding question

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague.  Can you be a little more specific in what you are having problems with?  Are you having trouble accessing the datasets in your SAS library?  Here is an example of an analysis where I have a dataset called airquality.sas7bdat and it's stored in a my "D:\analysis" directory on windows:

```
libname mydata "D:\analysis";

  proc timeseries data=mydata.airquality
                   out=series
                   outtrend=trend
                   outseason=season print=seasons;
      id date interval=qtr accumulate=avg;
      var air;
   run;
```

Comment: I can import the data but am facing difficulty in running the Unobserved components model. first I import the data using the option file-> Import Data then I use the command Print data -> Proc print data= file name .I run the UCM command using the command proc ucm data=filename; id year interval=year; model variable; irregular; level; slope; estimate;run;. However I get the error "the id value at observation number 2 is invalid. I am able to run UCM for the help datafile in SAS (SeriesG air) but not for my actual data. what does this message mean?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you possibly post the entire SAS Long or upload it somewhere for download and examination?  How you taken a look at the value of the year variable for observation 2?

Comment: My data is:**DEF-CO**= 233.3944, 309.197, 535.0094, 452.1551, 600.2667, 550.9203, 547.596, 720.1657, 849.6598, 830.7029, 917.2491, 908.1212, 1063.194, 1867.679, 1871.388, 2299.352, 2555.162, 2042.967, 2813.212, 2058.485, 2118.163, 2271.529, 2312.533, 2120.092, 4851.052, 6078.45, 6778.045, 6243.333, 5902.702, 9836.187, 10611.24, 9184.143, 9464.442, 10662.04, 8071.836, 6877.493, 22401.15, 21240.68, 20781.17, 17810.42, 15216.96, 16273.06, 16889.48, 15656.33, 14583.12, 13930.9, 21160, 50382.8, 58402.63, 63535.82, 38698.26, 55791.92, 64941.99.

Comment: The log is **
Proc print data= file name; 
Run; 
proc ucm data=filename; 
id year interval=year; 
model cop;
irregular; 
level; 
slope; 
estimate; 
forecast lead=24 print=decomp; 
run;**
I get the following error **ERROR: the ID value at observation number 2 is invalid**

Comment: Please edit your question with this information and use proper markdown so we can interpret it easier. (code should be separated from comment with blank lines and indented 4 positions.)